# How to attach cables to micro JST pins

Tags: soldering, crimp

Are there any methods to attach cables to micro jst pins without soldering nor crimping tools? I can't solder the cables in place due to how small the holes for the female jst pins that any amount of solder would prevent the female pins to connect to the male ones. I only got a set of pliers and im not able to buy other tools to assist, so are there any alternative ways to hold the cables in place and then crimping them?

Comment: You can get ready-made cables.

Comment: What is "micro JST"? JST have thousands of different connectors.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. as Andrew commented, get pre-made cables.
2. Get the correct crimper.

These connectors were not designed for soldering. Their plastic housing is relatively soft and melts at low temperature.
Also, when using such a process, the result is not reliable - the solder joint often breaks after mating.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any methods to attach cables to micro jst pins without soldering nor crimping tools?

Not if you are serious. You either need to get the correct crimping tool, or an IDC equivalent.

Many JST connectors come with an IDC socket option on the cable side, instead of crimp. If your specific family has such an option, then you can get a [hand tool](https://www.jst-belgium.be/images/categories/Banner-IDB-12.jpg) for IDC. These are much easier and faster to work with than crimping.

As mentioned, you can't really use soldering. Although if you are just making some dirty "lab junk" connection for prototype testing purposes, then here's a quick & dirty solution:

- Don't use the plastic socket part.
- Instead solder a wire onto the side of each crimp, where the wire would usually be attached.
- Wrap the crimp + wire in shrinking tube, isolating it on the sides.
- Then connect it wire by wire directly to the pin header.

This gives a good electrical connection but it's obviously a horrible mechanical solution.